# Watch videos with SUB/IDX subtitles

Tags: video

I have video files with their SUB/IDX subtitles.

I'm using [MX Player Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro) but it [does not support SUB/IDX subtitle](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510165637/https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/faq#TOC-SUB-IDX-subtitles-won-t-display.).

> #### SUB/IDX subtitles won't display.
>
> SUB/IDX subtitle is not supported as of yet. It will be supported in the future.

How can I watch videos on my Android device with SUB/IDX subtitles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere between [Nov 9, 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20141109194057/https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/faq) and [Apr 17, 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150417084556/https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/faq), [MX Player Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro) (and also its [ad-supported free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad)) supports both SUB/IDX subtitles.

> Subtitle formats:
>
> - DVD, DVB, SSA/ASS subtitle tracks.
> - SubStation Alpha(.ssa/.ass) with full styling.
> - SAMI(.smi) with Ruby tag support.
> - SubRip(.srt)
> - **MicroDVD(.sub)**
> - **VobSub(.sub/.idx)**
> - **SubViewer2.0(.sub)**
> - MPL2(.mpl)
> - TMPlayer(.txt)
> - Teletext
> - PJS(.pjs)
> - WebVTT(.vtt)

Answer (score 1):

You can use VLC to view videos with subtitles. Copy the subtitle files on the same folder as the video, then change their names to be the same as the video (don't change their extension).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an application like [MKVToolNix](https://mkvtoolnix.download/) on your PC, attach the SUB/IDX file to the video file, make one single video file with hard sub, and after that enjoy watching the video with hard sub on your Android device.